# Use jquery datepicker as a static calendar for informational purpose only

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to use the jQuery datepicker for information only.  For this reason I want to disable the "hover" effect and the color change when I click on a specific date.

I've try some combination but without any success.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use CSS to modify the styles.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/84b6G/)**

```
.ui-state-default, 
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, 
.ui-state-hover, 
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, 
.ui-state-focus, 
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus { 
    border: 1px solid #cccccc; 
    background: #f6f6f6 url(images/ui-bg_glass_100_f6f6f6_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #1c94c4; 
    outline: none;
    cursor:default;    
}​
```